# node-archiver : Getting duplicate parent zip upon extracting

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-archiver, archiverjs

I have written below for zipping a directory :

```js
const archiver = require('archiver');
let createArchive = function(sourceDir, destDir) {
    const archive = archiver('zip');
    const stream = fs.createWriteStream(destDir);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    archive
      .directory(sourceDir, false)
      .on('error', err => reject(err))
      .pipe(stream)
    ;

    stream.on('close', () => resolve());
    archive.finalize();
  });
}
```

Before zipping my directory looked like this :

- excelArchive.zip
- test.txt
- test2.gz

When I unzipped the archive (called `yayy.zip`) it had these files in it:

- excelArchive.zip
- test.txt
- test2.gz
- yayy.zip

There is an invalid file called `yayy.zip` inside it. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `directory`, you can use [the `glob` method](https://www.archiverjs.com/docs/archiver#glob) to specify the files to zip. It takes [a second argument](https://github.com/yqnn/node-readdir-glob#options) where you can specify files to ignore.

```js
const archiver = require('archiver');
let createArchive = function(sourceDir, destDir) {
    const archive = archiver('zip');
    const stream = fs.createWriteStream(destDir);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    archive
      .on('error', err => reject(err))
      .pipe(stream)
      .glob(
        '**/*',
        {cwd: sourceDir, ignore: filename}
      )
    ;

    stream.on('close', () => resolve());
    archive.finalize();
  });
}
```

Comment: What is filename here, i think i want to avoid yayy.zip which was not existing earlier. It got created by default inside the zip, so filename param won't work ( as it is non-existent at the time of generation ). Also can you help me undertsand why it happened in first place.

Comment: It's obviously the filename you want not to include in the zip file. i.e. the name of the zip file itself.